# How to get Get Process By Name on Mac Os?

Tags: c++, unix, process, osx-lion

So I want to get a process pointer and do something like Win32 `WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, INFINITE);` that would wait for process to quit if it is not null. How to create such GetProcessByName function for Mac/Unix like Os?

Answer (score 2):

Look at `[NSWorkspace runningApplications]` and `[NSRunningApplication  runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:]`. You can KVO observe NSRunningApplication's `terminated` property. You can also watch the notification `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`.

These are all 10.6+. If you need earlier versions, update your question with your version requirements. It's possible in older versions, but 10.6 made it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can only wait for a child process anyway, and if it's a child process you would have its PID (I never forget the names of my children; just their birthdays).

See: [waitpid(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

Comment: @myWallJSON You cannot wait for it to stop or become signalled.