# Get pid by process name on Mac OS X in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, macos, pid

I'm porting some linux code to mac os. On linux I was able to read the /proc/[pid]/comm file to get the pid of an process by it's name. However on mac os x is no /proc filesystem. So, how is it done on mac?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780718/how-to-get-get-process-by-name-on-mac-os

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using NSProcessInfo from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41184989/2630032)

Comment: I saw the answer, but it uses objective c. I would like to do it in pure c/c++